# How to access first element of NSDictionnary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I wrote a method that takes in parameter a SQL requests (`SELECT name FROM table`) and return a NSDictionnary with first letter of word as key

```
Dictionnary   
{   
  A = ("Arbre", "Armoise");  
  B = ("Bob", "Bill") ; 
  ...
}
```

So I'm stuck with that, Now if my request look like `SELECT name_en FROM table WHERE name_fr LIKE "Bob"`
My dictionnary will look like :

```
Dic {
      B = ("Bob");
    }
```

And I just want to display Bob. So How can I get this value ? I already tried `objectAtIndex` and `[[dic allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];`
But I got nothing

Thanks !

Comment: NSDictionary is not ordered, you have no guaranty that the order will stay the same. If you want "bob" you'd have to do `[dic objectForKey:@"B"];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as the "first object" in a dictionary. A dictionary is an unordered collection.

I'm not 100% certain what you're asking but what you could do is take the array of keys...

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
```

and then sort the array

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsing... // choose your own method for sorting
```

Then get the object related to the first sorted key...

```
id firstObject = dictionary[[sortedKeys firstObject]];
```